# RegexReplace the nth occurrence of a string of underscores

Tags: regex, google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble getting a `REGEXREPLACE` working in a Google Sheets formula. I'm aiming to replicate a certain card game which is opposed to humankind. I have a cell containing a string which contains one, two or three occurrences of a series of underscores, e.g.

"_____ is the new _____"

And let's say I want to substitute in the strings "Orange" for the first occurrence, and "Black" for the second occurrence.

I don't know how many underscores will be in each string, it could be one or more, so it seems like a job for regex. I tried `SUBSTITUTE` and it didn't seem to recognise asterisks. [Based on this link](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/nth-occurrence-of-a-string-or-number-in-google-sheets/), I tried using `{1}` `{2}` and `{3}` to match the first/second/third occurrence, but I'm not doing something right:

```
 =REGEXREPLACE(G16,".*(_*){1}.*",G17)
```

G16 is: `_____ is the new _____.`

G17 is: `Orange`

The output of the formula is: `OrangeOrange`.

Can anyone help me figure out the correct way to do this?

Comment: So, Orange is in some cell and where is Black?

Comment: Once I know how to apply a regexreplace to only the nth occurrence, then I can use the same formula again to replace Black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(G16,"^([^_]*)_+","$1Orange"), "^([^_]*)_+", "$1Black")
             |----- First occurrence -----------------|
 |----------------- Second occurrence ------------------------------------------|
```

[image]

**Details**

- `^`  - start of string
- `([^_]*)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` will refer to this group value): 0 or more chars other than an underscore
- `_+` -  1 or more underscores.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly! I've made one modification and made it a relative cell reference, but it works just fine if I change `"$1Orange"` to `"$1" & G17`. Cheers!

Comment: Just FYI: to replace the second occurrence of an underscore, one would use `"^([^_]*_[^_]*)_"`, third occurrence - ``"^([^_]*(?:_[^_]*){2})_"``, then just adjust the `{2}` quantifier to match other occurrences.